# what is the significance of "." in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am new to xsl and got stuck at a piece of the code. Can you please help me understand what the below code does and what does "." stand for.
here is the code: `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this do? <xsl:apply-templates select="."/> and <xsl:apply-templates select="\*|@\*"/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556967/what-does-this-do-xslapply-templates-select-and-xslapply-templates-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"." in XSLT (and XPath) represents the "context node" (or in 2.0, the "context item"). This is a very important concept to understand, and you really should do some reading because a short paragraph can't really explain it. Essentially, certain constructs change the context: for example, when you do xsl:apply-templates on a particular node, then in the selected template, that node will be the context node. When you do xsl:for-each, then each selected node becomes the context node in turn. Relative path expressions such as foo/bar navigate starting from the context node, and "." selects the context node itself.